# Do any of the flavors of regex in Regex Buddy coincide with NSRegularExpression (ICU) regex?

Tags: ios, regex, macos, nsregularexpression, regexbuddy

[NSRegularExpression](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) says its flavor of regex is "ICU."  I have RegexBuddy, which supports a bunch of different flavors, but none of them calls itself "ICU."  But is one of them ICU under another name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ICU is based on Perl regular expressions.